# C++ Forward method calls to embed object without inheritance

Tags: c++

I'm wondering if it's possible to automatically forward a method call to an embedded object, **without inheritance**. For instance:

```
class embed
{
public:
    void embed_method() {return};
};

class container
{
public:
    void container_method() {return;}
private:
    embed obj;
};

int main()
{
    container object;

    object.container_method();  // Local method call
    object.embed_method();      // 'Forward' call, obviously doesn't work
}
```

It could be very useful when inheriting from a base class is not possible / not recommended.
Currently, the only choice I have is to manually rewrite `embed` class methods into `container` class, and then call `embed` methods from `container` ones. Even if the process can be scripted, it's still annoying and it seems to be a bad solution.

Comment: You might make `container` behave like a smart pointer and overload applicable operators (->, *)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13885092/1147772 might help. Is private inheritance also out of question ?

Comment: @Drax yes, also out of question.

Comment: @DieterLücking I'll take a look, but I don't see how a smart pointer can help me in this case. Problem is that `embed` methods are still not defined in higher-level class (neither sp nor `container`).

Comment: I think you should rethink your design. Why do you want to expose the embedded object method? Maybe the code where you feel the need to call the embedded object method should be part of a method of the container object (e.g. Tell, don't ask)?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to do things against C++ rules. Is the laziness of writing a wrapper method the only reason for doing that?

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <utility>

class Embed {
 public:
  void embedMethod() { }
};

class Container {
 private:
  Embed embed;
 public:
  void containerMethod() {}

  template<typename ...Args, typename R>
  R forward( R (Embed::* function)(Args...), Args &&...args) {
    return (embed.*function)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
};

int main() {
  Container c;
  c.containerMethod();
  c.forward(&Embed::embedMethod);
}
```

[Live demo.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/87f43ace8cb2f6ae)

I'm not condoning the design, it is very poor encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

```
class embed
{
public:
    void embed_method(){return};
};

class container
{
public:
    void container_method(){return;}
    embed GetObj(){return obj;}

private:
    embed  obj;
};

int main()
{
    container object;

    object.container_method();  // Local method call
    object.GetObj().embed_method();     
}
```

Comment: the signature should be `embed& GetObj()` or `embed GetObj()`

Comment: @Samer Solution works but is not "user-friendly" (so sad that overloading `.` operator is forbidden...)

Comment: It is possible to overload the `operator()` of the parent class to get something like `object().embed_method()